# Extracting specific Win32 functions

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I want to use the CreateThread function from windows.h, but without all the #defines and crap that is included in the header file. Is there some way that i could import(I think thats what its called) just that function from the .dll or .lib?
tested and failed:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"Kernel32.lib")
__declspec(dllimport)
unsigned long
__stdcall
WaitForSingleObject(
    void* hHandle,
    unsigned long dwMilliseconds
    );


int main()
{
    WaitForSingleObject(0,0);
}
```

Comment: Curious, why do you care about all those defines etc? The preprocessor/compiler is doing all the hard work for you, so I don't see the gain in doing it yourself the hard(er) way. Also, *how* did it fail, did you get a specific error? Was it a compiler or linker error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two options:

1. You don't need to include the header.  The definition of `CreateThread` is not going to change.  You can just copy its declaration (and the declarations on which it depends) from the Windows headers into your own source file.
2. You can write wrappers around the Windows API functions that you use, then "pimpl" usage of the Windows API so that you don't have to include Windows.h and other headers all over the place.

In my opinion, the latter option is probably preferable as it is less error-prone, simpler, and provides isolation of nonstandard functions, making it easier to port the code.

Comment: I tried doing something like this. It resulted in an unresolved external error when placed in my source. but for some reason it worked when i copy and pasted it into the spot where the old definition had been in windows.h. Is there something special about windows.h?

Comment: Search for any `#pragma comment` in the headers; the headers may direct the linker to include libraries.  Alternatively, check MSDN for which import library should be used for the missing functions, and add those to your project's linker options.

Comment: already couldnt find any. Microsft says that CreateThread is in Kernel32.lib. since CreateThread's definition is so long i used WaitForSingleObject as a test: see question for source

Comment: The Windows API functions have C language linkage.  You need to add  `extern "C"` to the beginning of your declaration.  The Windows headers do this, typically by detecting when they are being included in a C++ translation unit and wrapping the whole header in an `extern "C" { /*...*/ }` block.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can load the DLL dynamically, get the address of the function and then call it. I'm not sure what your problem is with Windows.h though.

[LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Anyone who's been inflicted with `Windows.h` knows what the problem is.

Comment: ever tried to have a class A with a method called A::CreateFile and then notice that there's a linker error because the #define in windows.h renamed the method definition to A::CreateFileW or A::CreateFileA? windows.h is a mess.

Comment: GetProcAddress is in WinBase.h, which defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think DLLs dont have preprocessor directives because they're already compiled, so including the DLL shouldn't pollute your working set. If you want to include the source file (the *.h file), then you will need to compile those functions as well, which may very well depend on those directives and other crap.

Comment: how can you include a dll in c++ without a header file?